# How to get the latest duplicate into the database using SSIS

Tags: sql, visual-studio, ssis, duplicates, etl

I have a database table structure below:

CastingTable

- Date
- Time
- 2D-Code
- Value1
- Value2
- Value3

I have a folder contain millions of *.csv file to be extract and load to database by SSIS. Each file of csv contain 1 row of data. My problem is some of the file contain duplicate 2D-Code with other file and I want only latest 2D-Code file generated to be save to database. How can I achieve this ?

PS: I'm using VS2015 and MS SQL Server

Comment: How do you know what the `latest 2D-Code` file is? The file's create date? The Update date?

Answer (score 0):

**If you have a specific condition on the latest version, the following may be a solution :**

> ```
> CREATE TABLE CastingTable ([Date] DATE,
> [Time] TIME ,
> [2D-Code] VARCHAR(50),
> Value1 INT,
> Value2 INT,
> Value3 INT)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO CastingTable VALUES ('3-20-2021','13:30','AAA',1,1,1),
> ('3-21-2021','18:15','AAA',1,2,3),
> ('3-22-2021','10:00','AAA',7,5,6)
> ```

> ```
> WITH CTE AS (
> SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [2D-Code] ORDER BY [Date]DESC,[Time] DESC
> ) AS Rn FROM CastingTable
>
> )
>
> SELECT * FROM CTE
> WHERE Rn=1
> ```

> ```
> Date       | Time             | 2D-Code | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 | Rn
> :--------- | :--------------- | :------ | -----: | -----: | -----: | -:
> 2021-03-22 | 10:00:00.0000000 | AAA     |      7 |      5 |      6 |  1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=82eaf18f643334956d4dc94ff0a1be13)*

**If you want to get any unique record with a specific 2D-Code :**

In the Connection Managers area, right-click and select New connection. In the Add SSIS Connection Manager dialog box, select EXCEL and then Add.

On the SSIS menu, select New connection. In the Add SSIS Connection Manager dialog box, select EXCEL and then Add.

Drag the Sort Transformation task onto the design screen. Connect the OLEDB Source task to the Sort task.

Right click the Sort task and choose Edit. Sort your data by `2D-Code`, you'll notice down at the bottom, "Remove rows with duplicate values".